# Jquery trigger did not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <title>test trigger</title>
</head>
<body>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){ // on document ready
    $("#testbed").trigger('click'); // click the element
  })
  </script>

  <a id="testbed" href="http://www.google.com">testing</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect this code to automatically click the testbed link when the document is ready.  But the link is not clicked.

Comment: Is this your complete code? Because, if that is the case, you will have a parse error. At the end of your `$(document).ready({})` you are missing a semicolon `;` at the end

Comment: I don't see a reason why you would do this. It seems better to just do a plain redirect to your final destination - instead of trying to click an anchor. It seems like a roundabout way of getting to the destination

Comment: that does not produce a javascript error. semicolons are optional

Comment: FYI `$(document).ready()` doesn't take object it takes function, your code seems like it accept object `{}` in the `ready()` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

first you should know that `.trigger()` function cannot be used to mimic native browser events, such as clicking on a file input box or an anchor tag.

```
$("#testbed").trigger('click'); // it will not change the current page.
```

you have to use .simulate() to mimic such native browser events,

```
$( "a" ).simulate( "click" );
```

To use `.simulate()` function, you have to include `simulate.js` in your file.

you can refer to this page,
[triggering event handelers](http://learn.jquery.com/events/triggering-event-handlers/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define click on `testbed`

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // on document ready    
    $("#testbed").click(function(){ // on document ready
       alert("clicked");
    });
    $("#testbed").trigger('click'); // click the element
});
```

If you do not want to have click event and simply want to navigate to href of link then you can use `window.location.href = url;`

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // on document ready       
    window.location.href = document.getElementById("testbed").href;
});
```

Try **using native function and properties** etc where ever possible, to gain performance. You can check the difference in performance of different attributes access method over [**jspref**](http://jsperf.com/script-time-test).

Comment: why not `window.location.href = $("#testbed").attr("href");` since you're already using jQuery

Comment: Using native javascript code gives performace benifit, I like try using native function and properties etc where ever possible. You can check the difference in performance of $("#testbed")[0].href and $("#testbed").attr("href"); over here, http://jsperf.com/script-time-test

Answer (score 1):

The `click` event is triggered. Try for example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // on document ready
    $("#testbed").on ('click', function() {
        alert('click event');
    });

    $("#testbed").trigger('click'); // click the element
})
```

The actual action of visiting the URL in the `href` wont happen. You can use `window.location` to change pages and bypass jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ // on document ready
    var url = "http://www.google.com";
    window.location.href = url;
})
</script>
```

Comment: Google site just an example, I need to automatically click a function.

<a href="" data-filter=".mobile-ux-design" class="">Mobile UX Design</a>

<a href="" data-filter=".product-design" class="selected">Product Design</a>

Comment: and what if you change the variable url with class selected link? `var url = $(".selected").attr("href");`

Comment: What is your ultimate requirement? there could be some better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger is used to execute the click event which your link testbed does not have. If you want to redirect your page to that link why not use window.location.href

```
window.location.href = $("#testbed").attr('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

The .click() calls the defined click function. It does not simulate a user click.  The following code should give you the functionality you want.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

//Define click function
  $("#testbed").click(function(){
     window.location.href = $("#testbed")[0].href;
  });

//Trigger the click event.
  $("#testbed").trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){ // on document ready

   //Following code simulates a click event
    anchorObj =  $("#testbed")[0]; 
    var evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
      'view': window,
      'bubbles': true,
      'cancelable': true
    });
    anchorObj.dispatchEvent(evt);
  });
  </script>
```

This will work because it simulates actual click event on the anchor. But jQuery click will not work because it will only execute click handlers defined for the element.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ // on document ready
  $("#testbed")[0].click(); // click the element
})
</script>
```